# using twisted adbapi in ZSI soap

Tags: python, mysql, soap, twisted, zsi

I'm new to python and currently researching its viability to be used as a soap server. I currently have a very rough application that uses the mysql blocking api, but would like to try twisted adbapi.  I've successfully used twisted adbapi on regular twisted code using reactors, but can't seem to make it work with code below using ZSI framework.  It's not returning anything from mysql. Anyone ever used twisted adbapi with ZSI?

```
import os
import sys
from dpac_server import *
from ZSI.twisted.wsgi import (SOAPApplication,
                          soapmethod,
                          SOAPHandlerChainFactory)
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import MySQLdb

def _soapmethod(op):
    op_request = GED("http://www.example.org/dpac/", op).pyclass
    op_response = GED("http://www.example.org/dpac/", op + "Response").pyclass
    return soapmethod(op_request.typecode, op_response.typecode,operation=op, soapaction=op)

class DPACServer(SOAPApplication):
    factory = SOAPHandlerChainFactory

    @_soapmethod('GetIPOperation')
    def soap_GetIPOperation(self, request, response, **kw):
        dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("MySQLdb", '127.0.0.1','def_user', 'def_pwd', 'def_db', cp_reconnect=True)

        def _dbSPGeneric(txn, cmts):
            txn.execute("call def_db.getip(%s)", (cmts, ))
            return txn.fetchall()

        def dbSPGeneric(cmts):
            return dbpool.runInteraction(_dbSPGeneric, cmts)

        def returnResults(results):
            response.Result = results

        def showError(msg):
            response.Error = msg

        response.Result = ""
        response.Error = ""

        d = dbSPGeneric(request.Cmts)
        d.addCallbacks(returnResults, showError)

        return request, response

def main():
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    from ZSI.twisted.wsgi import WSGIApplication

    application         = WSGIApplication()
    httpd               = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8080, application)
    application['dpac'] = DPACServer()
    print "listening..."
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted creates a new `ConnectionPool` per (some kind of) request and it never stops the pool.  This means you'll eventually run out of resources and you won't be able to service any more requests.  "Eventually" is probably after one or two or three requests.

If you never get *any* responses perhaps this isn't the problem you've encountered.  It will be *a* problem at some point though.

On closer inspection, I wonder if this code even runs the Twisted reactor at all.  On first read, I thought you were using some ZSI Twisted integration to run your server.  Now I see that you're using `wsgiref.simple_server`.  I am moderately confident that this won't work.

You're already using Twisted, [use Twisted's WSGI server](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/wsgi.html) instead.

Beyond that, verify that ZSI executes your callbacks in the correct thread.  The default for WSGI applications is to run in a non-reactor thread.  Twisted APIs are not thread-safe, so if ZSI doesn't do something to correct for this, you'll have bugs introduced by using un-thread-safe APIs in threads.

Comment: This is just code to test twisted adbapi with ZSI soap, I'll eventually clean it up once I get it working. After a little more digging, it seems that the call to _dbSPGeneric(txn, cmts) is not being executed.

Comment: You might as well clean this up now since it could be causing your problem.

Comment: It did cross my mind that wsgiref.simple_server might not be using callbacks, and that's why adbapi was not working. Good to know you have the same suspicions. I'll try your suggestion to use twisted wsgi.

Comment: After more digging in ZSI docs, I found sample code that uses twisted.web2.wsgi and the adbapi works as advertised. The only thing is that the soap_GetIPOperation function returns right away without waiting for the sql query to return the results. Any ideas on how to tell the function to wait for the query results without blocking?

Comment: You really don't want to use twisted.web2.  It doesn't even exist in the Twisted version control system anymore (and hasn't for years now).  twisted.web.wsgi should work just fine.

I don't really know how ZSI works but the convention for handling asynchronous results is to return a Deferred.  Try returning a Deferred that eventually fires with the desired result from soap_GetIPOperation.  Perhaps ZSI will attach a callback to the Deferred to handle the result.

Comment: The quick way of doing it is using a loop to wait for all the callbacks to fire, but that's so kludgey and would probably block. Off to search twist for something more elegant. Thanks for all the assist.